# Illegal array-declaration in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, validation

Why doesn't this validate with the W3C validator:

3 variables from form.html going into form.php:

```
  <?php

   $stuff1 = $_POST["stuff1"];//catch variables
   $stuff2 = $_POST["stuff2"]; 
   $stuff3 = $_POST["stuff3"]; 
   $myStuff[0] = $stuff1;//put into array
   $myStuff[1] = $stuff2;
   $myStuff[2] = $stuff3;
  ?>
```

Comment: i think you might need key and a value, The post variable is array itself..

Comment: The W3C (html) validator is not supposed to see any php source code, only the output of your script. Since the code snippet you've provided doesn't print anything the validator should see ...nothing. a) post the original error message(s) b) provide the code that is responsible for the output.

Comment: Oh of course your'e right a certain difference.. there but the problem is with the print_r($myStuff) later on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why doesn't this validate with the W3C validator:

You may be misunderstanding something here. PHP code is generated on the server side, and outputs HTML (or not). Your abovementioned script will not pass any HTML validator, because to the validator, it will be empty. PHP and the W3C validator have nothing to do with each other.

If you are getting a *PHP* error message, please post it.

Comment: +1 - I think understanding that difference is probably more useful to the OP than dealing with what is wrong with his code; and for use of the word "abovementioned" (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abovementioned, for you doubters).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fine but try this too:

```
 $stuff1 = $_POST["stuff1"];
 $stuff2 = $_POST["stuff2"]; 
 $stuff3 = $_POST["stuff3"]; 

 $myarray = array();
 $myarray[] = $stuff1;
 $myarray[] = $stuff2;
 $myarray[] = $stuff3;

 print_r($myarray);
```

Also make sure that you put your fields inside a form eg `form` tag.

**Note** that php code is not something to be validated by the W3C validator, it is server-side generated code.

Comment: Yes your all correct with the difference some mistakes one make..., thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your array:

```
$stuff1 = $_POST["stuff1"];//catch variables
$stuff2 = $_POST["stuff2"]; 
$stuff3 = $_POST["stuff3"]; 
$myStuff = array();
$myStuff[0] = $stuff1;//put into array
$myStuff[1] = $stuff2;
$myStuff[2] = $stuff3;
```

and note [Pekka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235835/illegal-array-declaration-in-php/2235847#2235847) about the difference between PHP (server-side) and HTML (client-side).

Answer (score 0):

Try `var_dump($_POST)`

or a bit of validation

```
if (isset() && !empty($_POST["stuff1")) {
    $myStuff[0] = $_POST["stuff1"];
} else {
    echo '$_POST["stuff1"] error';
}
```

Check everything is being sent across correctly...